# understanding memory usage in Android

Tags: android, memory-management

i am trying to understand memory usage in Android.

when I run Norton Mobile Utilities, I see:
Resident Memory, Shared Memory and Effective Memory - can someone explain the difference between these?

Also, when I dump an HPROF file from eclipse, it says I'm using like 2.6MB of memory, but when I bring up a utility like Norton, it says I am using 31MB of resident memory, 18MB of shared memory and 13MB of effective memory -- say what??

Comment: @usery645402: You will be better off asking whoever wrote that utility.

Comment: Be specific and give more clarification on what you need actually

Comment: If You are asking something like.This would be helpful to you. Just find out , what do you need.[Java and android performance analysis, Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/search/label/memory)